# using recursion and a 2D array to make words intersect at similar letters

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, io

My class recently was assigned a program in which we need to create a crossword puzzle, using a 2D array, as well as recursion. The instructions are as follows:

***Write a program that reads words from an input file called words.txt, creating a crossword display maximizing the overlapping letters between words.  Assume the board has 15 rows and 15 columns.

The first line of the input file is ``a number representing how many words are present.  The words are then provided, one per line.  As your program runs it should display the solutions it finds, along with the count of number of overlaps for each one.  At the end it should display the solution with the maximum number of overlaps found, or a message if no crossword puzzle is possible.***

I am having a ton of trouble wrapping my mind around this concept. I understand the need for embedded 'for' loops to cycle the recursion, but I am not sure where to go from there.
Some sample code to get us started is as entails:

```
/* Dictionary.java
*    Read in words from a file.  The first line in the file should
*    be the number of words.  Subsequent lines have the words 
*    themselves, one per line.  For instance, a sample file 
*    could contain:
*       5
*           Java
*       Programming
*       Euphoria
*       Consternation
*  Education
*    
*    This sample code is not meant to be stand-alone, but rather
*    is meant for you to copy and paste into some other class.
*/

//the following are needed to implement reading from the file
import java.io.*;               // Used for IOException, File
import java.util.Scanner;       // Used for File input


public class ReadWords 
{
// Declare an array of strings to hold the words
String[] wordsArray;


// chain off to another method to avoid static errors
public static void main( String[] args) 
{
ReadWords theInstance = new ReadWords();
theInstance.doIt();
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read in the words 
void doIt()
{    // Use a try-catch block for exception handling. What this does is
// provide a place in your program to handle potential file read errors
try {
// Define a Scanner to read from an input file.  Note that the name of
// the file given in the code below MUST match the actual filename of
// the words file.  This file should be in the same directory
// as the source code for this project
File wordsFile = new File("words.txt");    // declare the file

// Ensure file exists and is in the correct directory
if( ! wordsFile.exists()) {
System.out.println("*** Error *** \n" +
"Your words file has the wrong name or is " +
"in the wrong directory.  \n" +
"It should be in " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\n" +
"\n" +
"Aborting program...\n\n");
System.exit( -1);    // Terminate the program
}
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner( wordsFile);

// while there are words in the input file, add them to the dictionary
int numberOfWords = inputFile.nextInt();

// use this value to allocate memory for the words array
wordsArray = new String[ numberOfWords];

// Now read this many words
for( int i=0; i< wordsArray.length; i++) {
// read next word and store into array
wordsArray[ i] = inputFile.next().toUpperCase();    
}

}
catch (IOException e)
{
System.out.println("Error in words file read");
System.exit( -1);
}

// echo the words found
System.out.println("The words read are: ");
for( int i=0; i< wordsArray.length; i++) {
System.out.println( wordsArray[ i]);
}
}//end doIt()

}//end class
```

If anyone has any suggestions or recommendations on where this should go, it would be most helpful.

Comment: It seems like you have not provided a specific question about a single issue but are asking for an overall solution. You have not given us an idea of the alg that should be used to figure this out.

Comment: I am having a difficult time figuring out where to start. I am not asking really for a solution, more so a recommendation of how I should get started on this.

Comment: Since it is unlikely that many of us have written a crossword app before, were you given guidance of an alg that could be used or are you just supposed to brute force it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here are my thoughts.
Given a 15x15 matrix, you have 225 possible positions at which a word may begin (depending on the length of the word). Additionally, for each position you have 2 possible directions. This gives you 450 possible places for a word.

I would do the following:

1. Create an object that will represent the state of the matrix (holding all words currently inserted). This object should have a method that given a new word will return all possible positions (and direction) that the word will fit. It should also keep track of the number of crossings.
2. Start with the first word,
3. find all the positions it will fit.

   a. if no positions found, this is a dead end. Return to the previous recursion.
4. For each position,

   a. create an instance of the matrix with the word in that position.

   b. get the next word and repeat 3 recursively until all words inserted

Comment: Thanks. This gives me something to try playing with.

Comment: Take care that you don't keep too many instances of the wrapper object around or you risk an out of memory error.

Comment: Question 2... since the input file 'words.txt' will give me an array of strings, and since the board is going to be an array of characters, would I be able to convert the string array to char array by matching the corresponding "charAt()" indexes and 2d char array indexes?

Comment: Sure. Although getting the `char[]` from the `String` and accessing the `char`s from the array might be more efficient than a bunch of calls to `charAt()`